# Как получить дни между двумя числами разделенными дефисом?

Tags: c#

Например есть значение переменной типа строка вида 1-5. Как получить последовательность дней (1,2,3,4,5) и проверить, если одно из этих чисел совпадает со значением переменной (например d = 3), условие выполняется.

Comment: Что уже сделали вы? Почему вы думаете, что за вас все должны писать?

Comment: естественно я сделал тоже... у меня есть вопрос я его задаю...

Answer (score 2):

Слишком просто, чтобы быть затруднительным.

```
var o = Convert.ToInt32(str.Split( new char[] {'-'}));
for (int i = 0; i < o; i++)
 if (o == d) something();
```